# Как получить текст в div?

Tags: javascript, парсер, casperjs

Пытаюсь с помощью casper.js получить текст, заключенный между тэгами div

```
casper.then(function() {
var ctitle = this.getHTML('#Mdoule-Div > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td:nth-child(2) > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(14) > td > table > tbody > tr:nth-child(2) > td > table > tbody > tr > td > div');
console.log('ctitle');
```

});

Путь до элемента беру из отладчика в хроме. Но ничего не выводит, что я делаю не так?

Comment: ничего не выводил ? судя по коду у вас должно выводить просто `ctitle` как строку